# Authentication for AngularJS partial

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, authentication, shibboleth

If an actual answer can't be given, maybe a pointer in the right direction?  I have googled my question a few different ways and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

My company uses Shibboleth for authentication, through the htaccess file like so:

```
SSLRequireSSL
AuthType Shibboleth
ShibRequireSession on
require AccountType staff trustee
```

When a user tries to access a site with this htaccess file, Apache redirects to our internal Shibboleth login page, and if successful, redirects back.  If I have this file in my www(top most that I have access to) folder, everything works great.  But I only want to protect certain subfolders, where users would have to sign in to see their specific information.

Everything I have searched for is using oAuth or some angular based internal authentication system.  Instead of having my co-workers create new logins, I would like to use the company ones they already have.

I'm using ngRoute and the files in the protected folder are the ones I want to protect.  If I put the htaccess file in the subfolder I'm trying to require a login for, the page never loads.

```
angular.module('recycleTracker').config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/viewTotal', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/viewTotal/viewTotal.html',
                controller: 'viewTotalController'
            })
            .when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/protected/register/register.html',
                controller: 'registerController'
            })
            .when('/viewTotalUser', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/protected/viewTotalUser/viewTotalUser.html',
                controller: 'viewUserController'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/viewTotal'});
}]);
```

I would like to have viewTotalUser and register restricted to logged in users only.

Is there a way that I can get the htaccess file to play nice with angular or am I misunderstanding the authentication code I've read.  Or is there something I can do with my routes to make this work?  We are only given the htaccess code to use.

Comment: Facing the same problem. When a user goes to a new state from within the app, Shibboleth does not trigger. It's only if you visit a URL directly does Shibboleth redirect.